# What command line options are available for test/unit in ruby 1.9.1?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit, ruby-1.9.1

What command line options are available if you're using the Test::Unit compatibility layer in ruby 1.9.1?

**Background**:

```
ruby test/test_all.rb --help
```

provides information on what command line options are available in ruby 1.8.7, but not in ruby 1.9.1 without the test-unit gem. Looking under Test and Test::Unit for ruby 1.9.1 [rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/index.html) doesn't help either.

Ruby 1.9.2 and later give useful output for the `--help` option.

Comment: Maybe I should file a bug report for this, if it's still valid.

Answer (score 1):

you can install the test-unit gem which I believe will show you command line options if you run it with --help

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I mentioned that it works with the test-unit gem in the question.